# How do I enable SMTP for my PHP contact form?

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp, contacts

I have successfully set up a php script for my contact form on my website but I have recently found out that my server provider does not accept php. Instead I have use SMTP.

Can anyone help me as this is new to me. I've attempted using other scripts but I cannot implement it.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "mail@louisreed.co.uk";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Your E-mail Address");
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://louisreed.co.uk');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

My HTML form:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <form role="form" action="http://www.louisreed.co.uk/includes/mailer.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" rows="1"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks! :)

Louis

Comment: smtp has nothing to do with your code it is in your php.ini file somewhere in you localhost. If you use mail() in php that uses your SMTP so if your provider doesn't support php you got a problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I sound like a noob but what is in my php.ini file? - I've had done a search but I cannot even find this file. Cheers

Comment: It is not that you can't find it. The problem is that your host is in control of this file.

Comment: Yeah my provider does not support php, what other options do I have?

Comment: @LouisReed Google how to connect to and send messages via SMTP in the languages your provider *does* support.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: The best solution for the problem is to change host / provider. Another option would be to use just a plain link to start outlook or an other mail service of the user. Such a link would look like this: `<a href="mailto:mail@louisreed.co.uk">Contact</a>` some more indept info on this could be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp. at the bottom of that page are 2 examples like I mentioned above

Comment: @SuperDJ Changing providers is VERY subjective as  'best solution', and w3schools is considered by many to be a resource to avoid.

Comment: @SuperDJ This is something I wanted to avoid! I want to have a nice contact form instead of using a mailto:

Comment: @admdrew I changed the `mailto?` to `mailto:` I know w3schools isn't the best but for this it does enough. I also know that changing host isn't the best solution for him right now but a host that doesn't support PHP?

Comment: I'm using North hosts, something I regret doing now! It was a good price but the service is not that great. In case I decide to change hosts - would you guys recommend anyone?

Comment: @SuperDJ https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - would this help me?

Comment: @LouisReed as it says in the title 'PHPMailer' it uses php so for you still not going to work

Comment: @LouisReed btw. the way you made your `$message` variable ins't going to work like you think it is. The first line of text would now be somewhere half of the page. Second each enter should be `\r\n` the way you did it will just make 1 line of text. Third each variable in your `$message` should be writen like: `{$variable}` or `".$variable."`. Both do the same trick but you need to do it like that else you will just see the variable as tekst and not the value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Oke I checked a few thinks. I guess you could atleast try the following. I know your host doesn't support php which find hard to believe tough. So maybe something else is wrong. What is the host you are using?

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    //Strip user input
    function sanitize($value) {
        //Escape the user input and then strip all html tags
        //mysql_* is not recommended but I guess you don't store data in a database
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($value));
        //Return the sanitized user input
        return $value;
    }

    //To display all errors
    function errors($error) {
        echo '<ul class="error">';
        foreach($error as $fail) {
            echo '<li>'.$fail.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    //All the input fields
    $name = sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
    $subject = sanitize($_POST['subject']);
    $message = sanitize($_POST['message']);

    //Check if there are no empty fields
    if(!empty($name), !empty($email) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)) {
        if(strlen($name) <= 3) {
            $error[] = 'Name '.$name.' is too short';
        }

        if(strlen($email) <= 3) {
            $error[] = 'Email '.$email.' is too short';
        }

        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error[] = 'Email '.$email.' is not a valid email';
        }

        if(strlen($subject) <= 3) {
            $error[] = 'Subject '.$subject.' is too short';
        }

        if(strlen($message) <= 8) {
            $error[] = 'Message is too short';
        }

        //If there are no errors
        if(empty($error)) {
            $to = "mail@louisreed.co.uk"; //The email you want to send it to
            //Subject already set
            $headers = "FROM: My site"; //Sets the headers
            //The message for the email
            $message = "Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:\r\n\r\nName: ".$name."\r\nEmail: ".$email."\r\nSubject: ".$subject."\r\n\r\nMessage: ".$message;
            $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            //If the mail has been send
            if($mail) {
                header('Location: http://louisreed.co.uk/index.php?success');
                exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $error[] = 'There are empty fields';
    }

    //If there are errors show them
    if(!empty($error)) {
        echo errors($error);
    }
}

//If issset success (from the header()) display a message
if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
    echo '<p>Thank you for your message</p>';
}
?>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So try the exact code I gave you above just copy and past it over the form code you have now. You can leave the rest of your code as is. After that save the complete file as `index.php`. After that remove the `index.html` file from your FTP. If you have done that you can upload the `index.php` file now check what you get. If there are still some errors please let me know